# Require js, TweenMax, IE8

Tags: javascript, requirejs, gsap

I have been wrestling a bit to get GreenSock JS (TweenMax) to work with require.js. I finally got it working in modern browsers, but IE8 is throwing weird errors.

My main require config file:

```
require.config({

  baseUrl: '/ui/js',

  paths: {
    jquery: 'modules/libs/jquery-1.10.2',
    tweenmax: 'modules/vendor/greensock-js/TweenMax'
  },

  shim: {
    jquery: {
      deps: ['constants'],
      exports: 'jQuery'
    },
    tweenmax: {
      exports: 'TweenMax'
    }
  }

});
```

My 'module' file:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'tweenmax'
], function($, TweenMax) {


  // Subscribe to the 'toggleFlyout' event
  // The event is used to open the flyout menu
  $(document).on('toggleFlyout', function() {
    var $html = $('html');
    var $page = $('.page');
    var openClass = 'js-flyout-open';

    if ( !$html.hasClass(openClass) ) {

      TweenMax.to($page, 0.2, {left:246, onStart: function() {
        $html.addClass(openClass);
      }});

    } else {

      TweenMax.to($page, 0.2, {left:0, onComplete: function() {
        $html.removeClass(openClass);
      }});

    }
  });



  // Publish the 'toggleFlyout' event
  // The event is published when the user click the menu button or the page overlay
  $(document).on('click', '.main-header__nav a, .toggle-flyout', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(event);
    $(this).trigger('toggleFlyout');
  });


});
```

IE8 is throwing the following errors:

```
Expected identifier                        TweenMax.js, line 2295 character 4
'TweenMax' is null or not an object        flyout.js, line 38 character 4
```

Note, that the code is working fine in modern browsers.

Comment: What is exactly on line 2295 in TweenMax.js?

Comment: Its pretty weird. Line 2295 is just a comment:    //@private feed in a camelCase property name like "transform" and it will check to see if it is valid as-is or if it needs a vendor prefix. It returns the corrected camelCase property name (i.e. "WebkitTransform" or "MozTransform" or "transform" or null if no such property is found, like if the browser is IE8 or before, "transform" won't be found at all)

Comment: Have you tried using the minified and latest version of TweenMax ( TweenMax.min.js ) .. it doesn't have that comment in the minified version, so IE8 won't throw that error :)

Answer (score 0):

TweenMax and Jquery are AMD modules since a very early version you don't not need shim config for them..
You should also compile your solution. 
Requirejs is better to run as dependency manager and packager than a module loader.
Use 
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs
for reference.